# Can't convert the PocketPC project in Visual Studio 2010 project format

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, visual-studio-2010

Just downloaded the Visual Studio 2010 Premium and realized that can't compile the project, made for PDA! 
 The error log in output window says: 
 Loading D:\Work...\PDA2.csproj ...
D:\Work...\PDA2.csproj : error  : The project file 'D:\Work...\PDA2.csproj' cannot be opened.
The project type is not supported by this installation.
 I want to know if mobile development projects are supported in RTM version or they are deprecated?

Comment: Did you download the RTM or RC?

Comment: RTM. Build:10.0.30319.1 RTMRel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IT doesn't look like it for devices running versions of Windows Mobile prior to 7.0. For developing apps for earlier devices, such as 6.5, you will need to keep to VS2008 [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t%28VS.100%29.aspx)